# Mat-autocomplete and mat-select overlapping my header

Tags: css, angular

`<mat-autcomplete>` and `<mat-select>` are overlaying my header. I have a sticky header and if I'm opening `mat-autocomplete` or `mat-select` and I'm scrolling, the list is overlaying the header. I saw that the content is in a div cdk-overlay-container. I've tried to use a bigger `z-index` for header but not works.

Comment: Paste your code here, whatever u tried

Comment: I've been there. I'm not sure what kind of layout you're using, but, in my case, the problem was the page top toolbar. After struggling for a while to push the toolbar on top of autocomplete panel, I realized that the UX became terrible. So I let the autocomplete panel cover the toolbar again. The solution in my case would be pushing the autocomplete panel downwards if it didn't fit the space between the autocomplete and the toolbar. Anyway, I don't remember what did I do to cover the panel, but I it was with a z-index (I think material z-index < 500... not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is: below I just want to make the slide toggle to not be covered by the panel. So I applied a class to its `div` container (`my-class`).

```css
.my-class {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2000;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

`z-index` must be higher than 1000 (`@angular/cdk/overlay`'s default z-index).

`position: relative` is important here, as, per css docs (w3schools):

> `z-index` only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky).

```html
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="State" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.name">
        <img class="example-option-img" aria-hidden [src]="state.flag" height="25">
        <span>{{state.name}}</span> |
        <small>Population: {{state.population}}</small>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>

  <br>

  <div class="my-class">
    <mat-slide-toggle 
      [checked]="stateCtrl.disabled"
      (change)="stateCtrl.disabled ? stateCtrl.enable() : stateCtrl.disable()">
      Disable Input?
    </mat-slide-toggle>
  </div>
</form>
```